# Java / Selenium relative paths

Tags: java, selenium

I have a relative file for a file upload

```
private String myPath= "..server\\app\\src\\test\\resources";
```

that is checked into source control.  Everyone will have the same file structure for their file including and after `server`.  However, since developers might have their repositories n different directories, I can't hard code the entire file path.  How can I get the fully qualified file path from the relative path?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String absolutePath = new File(myPath).getAbsolutePath();
```